# Is it time to repot my chili plants?

Tags: chili, repotting

I'm a first time grower in need of some advice: About three weeks ago (2018-01-20), a repotted my chili seedlings into the pots seen in the pictures. Is it already time to repot them again? The reason I ask is because they are starting to look a bit tired: the leaves are becoming more pale green (some a bit yellowish), and some are curling upwards. I can also see roots poking out from underneath the pots. Also the growth seems to be slowing down.

It seems reasonable that the above symptoms are due to lack of nutrition (the pots are quite small, so theres not too much soil in there.) It should be noted that I have yet to water with any nutrition.

If anyone knowledgeable could give some input/confirmation, I would very much appreciate it!

[image]
[image]

(Here are the links for larger images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Us3.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7fiF.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the roots are emerging from the pot there's not enough space in your pot so you need to size up for your plant. If growing from seed you will likely have to upsize 3-4 times before you reach your final pot.

https://www.wahaca.co.uk/2010/09/tips-from-the-chilli-expert-2-repotting-your-plants/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I will repot them in a couple of day (they seem to have recovered slightly, perhaps they dried out a bit too much before watering.) Do you think feeding with nutrients is too early?

Comment: Here is a recent article from Alys Fowler https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2018/jan/20/how-to-grow-chilli I tend to water everything with weak compost tea or aquarium water so I don't need to specifically add nutrients unless the plant is not doing too well.